# Vue 2: Best way to use v-model on custom checkboxes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Say, I have a custom checkbox (input) component, and I plan to use it with `v-model` in the component that is supposed to use it.

What I'm doing is, to support multiple checkboxes, I create an array state, and upon checking/unchecking, I add/remove the checkbox's value from the array.

Is the best approach. **I'm using Vue2**.

```
// CheckBox.vue
<script>
export default {
    model: { // Customising the option for model
        prop: "checked", // Array of checked values
        event: "check" // Firing this event with new array of checked values
    },
    props: ["name", "label", "value", "checked"],
    emits: ["check"]
};
</script>

<template>
    <label :for="`input-${name}`">
        {{ label }}
        <input :id="`input-${name}`" :value="value" type="checkbox" :checked="checked.includes(value)"
            @change="$emit('check', $event.target.checked ? [...checked, value] : checked.filter((val) => val !== value))" /> // I'm just appending/removing value from the array state. Is this the best approach?
    </label>
</template>
```

```
// SomeComponent.vue
<script>
import CheckBox from "../atoms/checkbox.vue";

export default {
    data: () => ({
        elements: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        checked: [], // Storing the checked values here
    }),
    watch: {
        checked: function (newSelected) { console.log(newSelected); }
    },
    components: {
        CheckBox
    }
}

</script>

<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="num in elements">
            <CheckBox :name="num" :label="num" :value="num" v-model="checked" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: I never tried with custom components, but if you emit the value you should be able to just `v-model="myArray"` and the value gets added/removed just like a regular input checkbox

Comment: @NicolaSpadari This may be the behavior in Vue3, but in Vue2, emitting the value itself replaces the state array with the value itself, causing errors. What you emit gets set as the new value itself.